# Apache rewrite .GIT url

Tags: git, apache, .htaccess

Im trying to figure out how to rewrite a url so that

```
mydomain.com/repositories/REPONAME.git
```

actually goes to

```
mydomain.com/repositories/REPONAME/.git
```

im using codeigniter so i already have some rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(repositories)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/repositories [NC]
RewriteRule ^repositories/(.*)/.git$ /repositories/$1.git [L,NC]
```

This will allow

```
mydomain.com/repositories/REPONAME/.git
```

to be redirected to

```
mydomain.com/repositories/REPONAME.git
```

Comment: So i guess i don't understand entirely. Right now that kind of works. It redirects any request for REPO.git to REPO/.git I don't want the user to see the redirect i just want the .git to be delivered. is that possible?

Comment: I think I misunderstood you and did it backwards. Please see if my updated answer works for you.